# how to get the decibel of byte audio data

Tags: java

i have been working on a java program that captures microphone audio byte data and then sends it to somewhere else (a part of my program), is there anyway i can calculate the decibel value of the data?
i am using TargetDataLine, in each iteration i am saving data to a tempData holder which i take and write it into a ByteOutputStream, in each iteration i am trying to calculate the decibel of tempData.

keep in mind i don't really understand a lot of things related to sound in computers and in java in general so please forgive me for my lack of knowledge.

this is class 1 or "foo", it's handling when to stop the capturing

```java
    public class Foo {
    public static void foo() {
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000.0f, 16, 1, true, true);
 
        try (
                var microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format))
        ) {
            var micListener = new MicListener(microphone);
 
            ByteArrayOutputStream allData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] tempData;
            final int chunkSize = 1024;
 
            while (true) {
                // in this case the loop goes forever, but in my program it stops when the user stops capturing audio.
                tempData = micListener.startRecording(chunkSize);
                
                //calculate the decibel value of tempData; Utils.calculateDecibel(tempData)
                //if decibel is high then do stuff
                if (decibel > 50)
                    allData.write(tempData , 0 , micListener.getNumOfBytesRead());
                
            }
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is class 2 or "MicListener", it's handeling capture of data

```java
public class MicListener {
    private final TargetDataLine target;
    private byte[] audioData;
    private int numOfBytesRead = 0;
 
    public MicListener(TargetDataLine target){
        this.target = target;
        audioData = new byte[target.getBufferSize() / 5];
    }
 
    public byte[] startRecording(int chunkSize) throws LineUnavailableException {
        numOfBytesRead = target.read(audioData , 0 , chunkSize);
 
        return audioData;
    }
 
    public int getNumOfBytesRead() {
        return numOfBytesRead;
    }
}
```

thanks for the help! have a great day

Comment: What does "_volume of the data_" mean? Audio pitch? Decibel?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar by volume i meant Decibel.
i will edit the post to better reflect on that

Comment: I doubt digitized sound has a concept of decibels.  If I play a sound file on a computer with the volume at 100%, then play the same sound file with the volume at 50%, what is the real decibel value of a particular instant in the sound data?  Which playback should be considered as supplying authoritative decibel levels?

Comment: Your data is 16 bit signed big endian, so to get the volume you can convert pairs of bytes to samples, and process them in whatever way you think appropriate to get the volume. You could find the peak absolute value for instance, or the average absolute value. What do you want to use the volume for?

Comment: @tgdavies can you explain what you mean by "convert pairs of bytes to samples" ?
should i can get pairs of bytes from the array, but what do you mean by "samples".
also, the use of the volume is stated in the question, i guess i want to get average absolute value